# Erro no PHP ao conectar com banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Apesar de eu não ter alterado em nada as configurações do meu banco de dados MySQL que tem funcionado bem há meses, a conexão parou de funcionar.

Este é o comando PHP que uso para fazer a conexão:

```
$this->link = @mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass) or die("Sem conexão ". mysqli_connect_error());
```

Mysqli_connect_error retorna esta mensagem de erro:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
```

Estas são as configurações de conexão do UOL Host:

```
public $host = "djbteste.mysql.uhserver.com";
public $user = "********";
public $pass = "********";
public $db = "djbteste";
```

Porém é um erro intermitente, acontece algumas vezes ao longo do dia e apenas por alguns minutos. Eu entrei em contato com o suporte (que é péssimo!) do UOL Host, e eles disseram que está tudo bem com o banco de dados...

Comment: Pode ser algum problema na infraestrutura que acarreta uma perda de pacote em momentos de pico, uma forma de contornar seria você remover o `die()` e colocar a linha de conexão dentro de um `while`, para tentar uma 2ª ou 3ª vezes (mas não muito) antes de interromper a execução.

Comment: obrigado @GiovanniNunes achei interesante sua sugestão e vou fazer este teste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar o IP do servidor na sua variável `$host`.

```
public $host = "127.0.0.1.00"; // IP do servidor
public $user = "********";
public $pass = "********";
public $db = "djbteste";
```

Outra coisa, insira o nome do banco também, assim:

```
$this->link = @mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass, $this->db);
```

ou assim:

```
$this->link = @mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
mysqli_select_db($this->link,$this->db);
```

Comment: Andrei Coelho, fiz as alterações que você sugeriu e vou observar durante algum tempo o desempenho do banco de dados. se solucionar o problema marcarei sua resposta como correta. obrigado!